# How do I say "I moved the table", meaning that I put it in a different place?

Tags: word-choice

I am aware of a number of Korean verbs meaning 'move'.

For a while I thought 움직이다 would have been right for this situation, but I'm not sure I've noticed Koreans using this in this way.

I've heard 이사하다 to talk about moving house, but not moving furniture.

Perhaps 옮기다 could be used? But I felt that put the focus on 'carrying' something, rather than the result of the action (the position change).

How do I say "I moved the table", meaning that I put it in a different place in the room?

Would it be a different word if I was moving it to a different room, or a different house? Or depending on *how* I moved it (carrying, pushing, etc.)?

Comment: @Rathony thanks for the edit - I looked that word up and *still* spelled it wrong!

Comment: Always my pleasure. A small tip. When you write a Korean word, it is helpful if you ask yourself if you are writing it as it sounds (소리 나는 대로). Most of the time, it is wrong if you write it as it sounds. You will get there if you keep practicing it. Cheers!

Comment: "Most of the time, it is wrong if you write it as it sounds." - that sounds interesting. If I asked a question here "How can I improve my spelling without looking every word up in a dictionary", do you think that would be too broad?

Comment: No, as long as it helps learners, why not? But some examples like 움직이다, 움지기다 would be helpful and make it less broad. :-)

Comment: Also keep in mind that 이사하다 is an intransitive verb: when you move, you just say "이사했어요", not "집을 이사했어요".

Comment: @jick No. The line between a transitive verb and an intransitive verb in Korean is less clear than English. "이사하다" has an implied object "집을" and I don't think it is necessarily an intransitive verb. If it is an intransitive verb, you can never say "여러 집을 이사하다 (move houses many times)". Personally I think it is absurd to classify a verb as transitive and intransitive in all languages that I have learned. But it would be very controversial and I know I am not on a winning side of this argument.

Comment: @Rathony I agree that the line between transitive/intransitive verbs is blurrier in Korean, but there's definitely distinction---or, rather, a gradient of verbs ranging from "almost always with an object" to "almost never".  Besides, some phrases can take 을/를 even though they don't look like a proper object.  (Not sure how grammarians analyze this.)  E.g., "**여러 번을** 쓰러졌다", "책을 **세 시간을** 읽었다".  I think your "여러 집을 이사하다" example is more along this line, indicating repetition rather than being an actual object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an easy question to answer, but I will try using some examples as they might sound the same to learners.

The verb '움직이다' sounds more general than '옮기다' or '이동하다'. For example, if you find a person unconscious who can move only his eyes, you can ask

> 내 말이 들리면 눈을 움직여 보실래요? (Literally) Can you move your eyes if you hear me?

Here, '움직이다' means a very small movement. How far can you move your eyes? Not very far. Therefore, if you say "책상을 움직였다." you never know whether you moved it an inch to balance it or to move it to another room. But it is more likely that people would understand you moved it a little bit so that you can find something or adjust its balance.

'[옮기다](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=28021900)' implies moving from A place to B place. It is a causative form of the verb '옮다' which means 'catch (a disease or infection)'. A disease should (literally) move from one patient to another if he gets infected. Therefore, 옮기다 has this connotation. If you say, "책상을 옮겼다." it would mean you moved a desk from A place to B place.

You could consider using '[이동하다](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=30382902)', but it sounds less colloquial because '이동' is from Chinese characters.

You can never use '이사하다' as it means (as you mentioned) moving to a different house unless you want to make a joke.

> 내 말이 들리면 눈을 옮겨 보실래요?

It sounds very weird because there is no place to move your eyes to.

> 내 말이 들리면 눈을 이동해 보실래요?

It sounds weird, too, albeit not as much as "눈을 옮겨 보실래요?".

I don't think there is a different word that indicates how you moved it (carrying, pushing, etc.). '밀어서 움직이다, 옮기다, 이동하다' mean 'move something by pushing it' and '들어서 움직이다, 옮기다, 이동하다' mean 'move something by lifting it'.